# MongoDB Geospital compound indexing return error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I am trying to make an index over my collection in MongoDB. But I am getting error of

```
point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ]
```

This is the query I am trying to run.

```
db.col_name.ensureIndex({zloc:"2d",title:1,isPublished:1,finishDate:1});
```

And the structure of my document is below. I googled it but not found any satisifed solution really.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "518b758558266943c9ffa0d0"
},
"startDate": null,
"detail": "<p><strong>Fa&ccedil;iba Brunch Keyfi</strong><p>",
"imageUrl": [
    "http://img2.fbfcdn.com/files/images/deal/image/450_H/55/556101_fe85.jpg?r=3"
],
"isPublished": "on",
"category_id": 9,
"finishDate": null,
"webLink": "http://www.firsatbufirsat.com/firsat/",
"shopname": "Façiba & Deha Pansiyon & Restaurant & Cafe & Bar",
"publisher": "web",
"title": "Façiba'da Damak Zevkinize Hitap Edecek Açık Büfe Brunch Keyfi, Sucuklu Yumurta, Patates Tava ve Sınırsız Çay Eşliğinde 35 TL Yerine Sadece 18 TL",
"duration": 0,
"price": "18.00 TL",
"zloc": [
    41.144269,
    29.590859
],
"category_name": "Yemek Fırsatları",
"address": "Ahmetli Köyü Sortullu Mevkii İdeal Cad. No:9 Şile, İstanbul",
"user_id": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index you are setting up looks correct according to your document structure.  What Mongo is telling you is that there is an entry in your database where the latitude or longitude falls outside of the allowed range.

Try running the following queries to confirm this:

```
db.col_name.find({"loc.lat": { $lt : -180 }}).count();
db.col_name.find({"loc.lat": { $gt : 180 }}).count();
db.col_name.find({"loc.long": { $lt : -180 }}).count();
db.col_name.find({"loc.long": { $lt : 180 }}).count();
```